# Why does the while loop does not work in Roblox for me

Tags: lua, roblox

I want to create a script that will let the object named "Part" change its color from "Really Black" to "Neon Green" every 2 seconds. Would anybody be able to point out any flaws in my code or whatever I am doing wrong , the following are my lines of code :

```lua
local Part = game.Workspace.Part
while true do
    Part.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Really Black")
    wait(2)
    Part.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Neon Green")
end
```

I tried this line of code , I expected the block to change colours but its stuck on the color "Really Black"
and does not change to "Neon Green" even after 10 seconds or so , I am unable to find a solution for this.

Answer (score 1):

After `Part.BrickColor=BrickColor.new("Neon Green")` you have no wait, so it is looping immediately to `Part.BrickColor=BrickColor.new("Really Black")`. That quick you haven't chance to see. Just add second wait at the end of loop.

Answer (score 1):

In your implementation in the while loop your code starts by setting the color of object "Part" to "Really Black" and after waiting for 2 seconds it changes the color of "Part" to "Neon Green" but immediately as the next iteration comes, changes back to "Really Black".

To fix this implement another `wait()` call after the last line of the `while` loop block as follows

```lua
local Part = game.Workspace.Part
while true do
    Part.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Really Black")
    wait(2)
    Part.BrickColor = BrickColor.new("Neon Green")
    wait(2)
end
```